Getting non-obvious value for XIRR returns in Google sheets
I assume for a periodic return of 1% per month, I should see an XIRR of 12%, but I am getting values of 8.86198E+165. The table I used is



Date
Cashflow




1 Jan 2024
-10000


1 Feb 2024
100


1 Mar 2024
100


1 Apr 2024
100


1 May 2024
100


1 Jun 2024
100


1 Jul 2024
100


1 Aug 2024
100


1 Sep 2024
100


1 Oct 2024
100


1 Nov 2024
100


1 Dec 2024
100


1 Jan 2024
100


1 Jan 2024
10000



The formula I used is =XIRR(Cashflow amounts, Dates).
When I use the formula for IRR, I get the expected answer of 12%. i.e. =IRR(Cashflow amounts)
What am I missing?

It looks like the last two dates should be 1 Jan 2025, not 2024.  Setting them to 2025 produces the XIRR result below.
XIRR calculates using the actual number of days in the months, then annualises the result.  Since the number of days varies the result is not exactly 12%.  If you want to calculate using idealised months you can use IRR and annualise the result.

The actual calculation used by XIRR is like so.

With the above figures, daily compounding.
-10000/(1 + r)^(0/366) +
   100/(1 + r)^(31/366) +
   100/(1 + r)^(60/366) +
   100/(1 + r)^(91/366) +
   100/(1 + r)^(121/366) +
   100/(1 + r)^(152/366) +
   100/(1 + r)^(182/366) +
   100/(1 + r)^(213/366) +
   100/(1 + r)^(244/366) +
   100/(1 + r)^(274/366) +
   100/(1 + r)^(305/366) +
   100/(1 + r)^(335/366) +
   100/(1 + r)^(366/366) + 10000/(1 + r)^(366/366) == 0

Solving: r = 0.1268433
and annualising: (1 + r)^(365/366) - 1 = 12.6476%
However in the screenshot above the XIRR is an effective annual rate and the IRR is a nominal annual rate compounded monthly. So for fair comparison we can convert the 12.6476% effective rate to a nominal rate.
XIRR nominal rate: (1 + 0.126476)^(1/12) - 1)*12 = 11.9687%
while the IRR nominal rate is: 12%
On a non-leap year the XIRR would be 12.0031%

Thank you so much for the detalied explanation. It improved my understanding of XIRR, IRR. Thanks for taking the time to patiently type so much stuff.

@Sharad You're welcome
